# HttpClient after internet reconnected "The remote name could not be resolved"

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

**Context**
I have a laptop in a corporate network using a proxy.
When I use the HTTP client (.NET Framework 4.8) in an application it works fine.
When I unplug internet, I get `The remote name could not be resolved` which makes sense.

However, when reconnecting internet while the app is still running, I keep getting `The remote name could not be resolved` even though I can verify it is working from my browser.

Restarting the application makes everything work again.

I have a small reproducible example combining things I found in different blog posts about other issues related to `The remote name could not be resolved`.

**Question**

Is there some caching being done somewhere deep internal? In the example I have new `HttpClient`'s, new `HttpClientHandler`'s, set the `ConnectionClose` header and put the `ServicePointManager`. If there is, how can I manipulate it?

(*sidenote*: When I'm using this in my applications outside this small reproducible example I'm using the `AddHttpClient<TI,T>` where the containing classes are not singleton and have this same result.)

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));
            sp.SetTcpKeepAlive(false,0,0);
            sp.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15).TotalMilliseconds;

            ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15).TotalMilliseconds;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Press Key to try send");
                        Console.ReadKey();

                        var uri = "https://www.google.com";

                        var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
                        message.Headers.ConnectionClose = true;
                        message.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
                        {
                            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                        };

                        var response = await client.SendAsync(message);
                        Console.WriteLine("Success:");
                        Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**

After reading some tracing thanks to [@Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li)
I saw the following.

Request 1: Connected
`System.Net Verbose: 0 : [25368] Entering ServicePoint#6044116::ServicePoint(myproxyaddress:8080)`

Request 2: Disconnected
`System.Net Verbose: 0 : [29900] Entering ServicePoint#3507177::ServicePoint(www.google.com:443)`

Request 3: Reconnected
`System.Net Information: 0 : [29900] Associating HttpWebRequest#37200859 with ServicePoint#3507177`

So it connects to the wrong servicepoint.

When I move the `HttpClient` and `HttpClientHandler` creation out of the loop, it works.
It however does not work if I start from a disconnected state (due to associating with wrong servicepoint).

I Think I need to explicitly set the proxy settings when applicable instead of letting .NET figure it out and caching it wrongfully.

**Update**

Indeed, explicitly setting the proxy address worked. This allows for no mistakes when .NET tries to figure out how to connect by itself. However if you hardcode the proxy settings it cannot correct itself when they change.

```
      var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
      {
          Proxy = new WebProxy("myproxyadress:8080")
      };
      var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: You can enable System.NET tracing to learn more about the underlying activities, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing

Comment: Thanks @LexLi What I'm seeing is that in the scenario before disconnection it enters a servicepoint using the proxy address (e.g. myProxyAddress:8080). After disconnect it enters a servicepoint with the request address (e.g. www.google.com). When reconnecting it still goes to that reqeust address service point. Is there a way to force a service point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digged through some tracing thanks to suggestion from [@Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li)

Explicitly setting the proxy address worked. This allows for no mistakes when .NET tries to figure out how to connect by itself by associating requests with potentially wrong service endpoints.

```
  var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
  {
      Proxy = new WebProxy("myproxyadress:8080")
  };
  var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

**Edit**: This is not a good solution because it cannot handle with proxy changes. Using `WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()` will.

```
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
   Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy(),
};
```